# Speakerbox IOS callkit UI hides itself after call receive

Tags: ios, callkit

After accepting incoming call on speakerbox iOS, the UI which shows caller name and timer on native call controller goes back of the app. Is there a way to take that to the front form where user can disconnect, mute and see the timer.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is in the foreground, it is responsible for showing a UI for the call (for example, what does your app do on iOS 9?). So by bringing your app to the foreground, that is enough.